# Is there a Kivy equivalent of tkinter's LabelFrame?

Tags: python, kivy

I am exploring the possibilities of Kivy to design a UI application in Python 3. I was looking for a container widget that has a title label and ideally a border (like tkinter.ttk.LabelFrame), but could not find any in Kivy's documentation (neither here or google).

I think I understand there are standard widgets and many others done by 3rd parties (that should be available through 'garden'), but I have not found a repository of all 3rd party widgets available (if such thing exists).

Comment: What kind of design do you want to achive? In kivy almost everything is a widget. Every widget has a canvas, which itself is structured in a before, standard and after order. You can draw almost everything on this canvas which means you are completely free to design your label according to your purposes. You can even give a label button attributes by inherinting the buttonbehaviour class. If you tell me whats your goal I can give you an example. Is it just text and border?

Comment: @MisterNox, yes, text and border. I could not submit a picture, but I am trying to achieve the look of  Check Group in this [LabelFrame screenshot](https://studyfied.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/LabelFrame-widget-eample.jpg).  So I would need a border (sunken possible?), add a label over a top part of the border and adding a container of reduced size for elements, so they don't overlap with the border.